# Degenerate bilinear form and the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra

> A nondegenerate or nonsingular form is one that is not degenerate, meaning that $  {\displaystyle v\mapsto (x\mapsto f(x,v)}  $ is an isomorphism, or equivalently in finite dimensions, if and only if
>   $f ( x , y ) = 0  $  , for all $y ∈ V $  implies that $x = 0$.***Wikipedia***[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_bilinear_form]

If we consider $v_1\:\text{and}\:v_2$ to be orthogonal with respect to the bilinear form then we have $f(v_1,v_2)=0$ and none of them is in the nullity $V_0$.

**Question**:

How cannot the dual space  be isomorphic if the bilinear form is degenerate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In finite dimension, the dual space $V^*$ is *always* isomorphic to $V$. The point is that the linear map $$\Phi \colon V \to V^*, \quad v \mapsto f(v, \, \cdot)$$
provides an isomorphism if and only if the bilinear form $f$ is non-degenerate.

In fact, $v \in \ker \Phi$ if and only if $f(v,\, w)=0$ for all $w \in V$.